# Set method as Post but When submit as form.submit(),It send GET request instead of POST

Tags: javascript, jsp, safari, cross-browser

Code is looking like:

```
<form name="abc" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="x" id="x">
    <input type="hidden" name="y" id="y">
    <input type="button" onclick="fnSubmit();">
</form>

<script>
    function fnSubmit() {
        document.forms['abc'].action = "someUrl";
        document.forms['abc'].submit();
    }
</script>
```

Issue is occurring in safari 5.1.5.
Same is working fine in safari 5.0.1.

Comment: a `>` is missing on button element

Comment: In my code it is, button tag is properly close.

Comment: Actually request is going but not POST. it is happening as GET

Comment: You need to show us your real code, otherwise we'll never know what's going on here.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to submit as a post in Safari 5.1.7 (windows)

```
<form name="abc" method="POST" onsubmit="fnSubmit();">
    <input type="hidden" name="x" id="x">
    <input type="hidden" name="y" id="y">
    <input type="submit" name="test">
</form>

<script>
    function fnSubmit() {
        document.forms['abc'].action = "http://www.foo.com/bar.php";
    }
</script>
```

Could you do something like this?